# Placing tr:nth-child(even) inside a table tag

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to put a tr:nth-child(even) inside a table tag. I do not want it global.

EXAMPLE:

```
<table style= "{tr:nth-child(even) = background-color: #c2ddf2;}"> 
   <tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Four</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this</th><th>should</th><th>be different</th><th>colors</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this should</th><th>be same</th><th>colors as</th><th>first row</th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Pseudo-classes can't be set in style attribute. Use a `<link>` or `<style>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a class to the table and you're good to go!

```css
.special tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #c2ddf2;
}
```

```html
<table class="special"> 
   <tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Four</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this</th><th>should</th><th>be different</th><th>colors</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this should</th><th>be same</th><th>colors as</th><th>first row</th></tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table class="notspecial"> 
   <tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Four</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this</th><th>should</th><th>be different</th><th>colors</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this should</th><th>be same</th><th>colors as</th><th>first row</th></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-classes can't be set in the style attribute. Instead, you can give a class to table and do like this

```css
.table1 tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #c2ddf2;}
```

```html
<table class="table1" > 
   <tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Four</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this</th><th>should</th><th>be different</th><th>colors</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this should</th><th>be same</th><th>colors as</th><th>first row</th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What part of this is unclear to you: `I am trying to put a tr:nth-child(even) inside a table tag. I do not want it global.`?

Comment: @NisargShah `inside a table tag` means??

Comment: I don't think what OP is trying to accomplish is to put it inside the table tag, but rather have it on one table specifically. This answer provides the desired result.

Comment: OP wants inline style. They know that declaring CSS separately would work.

Comment: and Pseudo-classes can't be set in the inline style attribute. That's why we put it separately

Comment: Maybe OP is new to HTML/CSS? How do you know that he knows? No need to lash out at @Sanchit Patiyal

Answer (score 1):

You cant style pseudo element with inline css. Here is how you can do that.

```css
.table tr:nth-child(even){
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="table"> 
   <tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Four</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this</th><th>should</th><th>be different</th><th>colors</th></tr>
   <tr><th>this should</th><th>be same</th><th>colors as</th><th>first row</th></tr>
</table>
```